# How to filter in Author column in SharePoint Onpremise using REST API?

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, sharepoint-rest-api

I have tried below URL for filter using Author column in list in REST API.

siteURL/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ABC')/Items?select=*&$filter=AuthorId%20eq%201

but it doesnt work in OnPremise. It works as expected in SharePoint Online.Please provide solution if anyone have.

Comment: try using $expand=Author and then $filter=Author\AuthorId

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you expand the field Author, you can filter it.
Example:

```
$filter=Author/Id eq 18&$expand=Author&$select=Author/Id,Title
```

Greetings

is it possible without select parameter ? No, it's not, when you expand a field you must provide the select with the output fields.

Comment: One is happy to be of service :)